# How to add a small dash under a word?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web

[image]

How do I add that small dash under the word? Border bottom doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:after` pseudo element to create line with custom width.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #335072;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">VIEW ALL DEALS</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

To build on previous answers:

```css
.partial-underline {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #00008b;
    font: bold 20px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}

.partial-underline::after {
    content: '';
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #ff4500;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 8px auto auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="partial-underline">View all deals</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I also use the pseudo-element 'after' but I am using margin: auto to center the small dash underneath the text. To read what a pseudo-element is you can navigate to the following page: [W3Schools - CSS Pseudo Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of CSS pseudo-elements here, then use the positioning for alignment and regular box-model properties to give the dash the size you want to achieve.

Here is what I came up with, with a little more hover enhancement. It looks almost the same as the screenshot you shared in the question:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 }

.dashed {
  position: relative;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: .75em;
  
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  color: #333;
}

.dashed:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;

  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  
  content: "";
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: width .1s ease-in-out;
  
  background-color: orange;
}

.dashed:hover:after {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a class="dashed" href="#">View All Deals</a>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks it worked, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
.text {
    color: blue;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dash {
    color: orange;
    border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 34%;
}
```

```html
<a class="text" href="#">VIEW ALL DEALS <span class="dash"></span></a>
```